# Maximised application windows incorrectly positioned after unlocking when using Dash to panel

Tags: gnome, window-management, maximize

I'm using Fedora 37 with gnome 43.2.

I prefer a windows style workflow, with a bottom task bar, start menu etc. To achieve this, I've installed the gnome extension "Dash to panel", which works great in general, but I am running into one issue.

When I maximise a window, it takes up the whole screen, minus the bottom task bar, as expected. However, if I lock and then unlock the computer, the window remains maximised but is positioned incorrectly; there is a gap at the top (where the panel originally was), and the bottom section of the window is behind the task bar.

It's not a huge issue, I just have to un-maximise (?) and then maximise the window again, but it is a little annoying.

Has anyone run into this issue before and have a possible fix?